# Conditions on $K(X)/K(X^n)$ being Galois

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions

Statement: $K(X)/K(X^n)$ is Galois if and only if $p$ doesn't divide $n$ and $K$ contains all the zeroes of the separable polynom $g := X^n-1 \in K[X]$. (the polynom is certainly separable because $p$ doesn't divide $n$, so the roots of $g$ is unique.) For simplicity we denote from now on $E$ the set of all the roots of $g$.

But I have doubts about the statement, I can see how the direction (<-) goes: $K(X)$ = $K(X^n)(F)$, $F$ is the zeroes of a separable polynom $f := Z^n-X^n \in K(X^n)[Z]$ ($f$ is separable since $eX$ is a root of $f$ for all $e \in E$ and $|E| = n$) so the extension $K(X^n)(F)/K(X^n)$ is Galois.

For the other direction (->) we assume $p$ divides $n$. Let $n =mp^r$ where $r \geq 0$ and $ggT(p,m) =1$. Then $f$ is no longer separable since we have $f = Z^{mp} -X^{mp} = (Z^m-X^m)^p.$ And I don't know how to proceed from here, is it possible that the statement is not true?

Maybe it can help if we can find the minimal polynom of $X$ in $K(X^n)$? is it $Z^n-X^n$? (assuming $p$ doesn't divide $n$)

---

Update:

To prove (->): Assume $p$ divides $n$ Let $n =mp^r$ where $r \geq 0$ and $ggT(p,m) =1$. So we have $f = Z^n-X^n = (Z-e_1X)^p ... (Z-e_mX)^p$.
Since the extension is Galois, we know that the minimal polynom $\mu_{X,K(X)/K(X^n)} \in K(X^n)[Z]$ is separable and it divides $f$ so it can take at most $m$ factors of $f$, since otherwise we would have doubles. This shows that the minimal polynom would have terms $X^i$ in it with $i \leq m < n$, hence it cannot be in $K(X^n)$, a contradiction.
Therefore $p$ cannot divide $n$.

We now know that $p$ doesn't divide $n$, hence $|E|=n$. Furthermore, we know $h:= \mu_{X,K(X)/K(X^n)}$ divides $f$, which in this case can be written as $(Z-e_1X)...(Z-e_nX) \in \overline{K}(X)[Z]$ with $e_i \in E \subset \overline{K}$, we say $h$ must be equal to $f$, then otherwise we would again have terms $X^i$ with $i<n$ in it, which should never happen. Since the extension is Galois, we have $h = \prod_{b \in Gal(K(X)/K(X^n)).X}(Z-b)$, hence $e_iX \in K(X)$ and $e_i \in K(X)$, but $\overline{K}$ was constructed independently of $X$, therefore $e_i$ cannot be expressed in terms of $X$, therefore $e_i$ is in $K$ for all $i$, i.e $K$ contains all the zeroes of $g$, as required.

Comment: @FShrike We know the zeroes of $f$ explicitly ($eX$ for all $e \in E$) that means $f$ is separable, we can write $f = (Z-e_1 X)...(Z - e_n X), e_i \in E$

Comment: @FShrike why is it obviously not $Z^n-X^n$?

Comment: @FShrike Right, sorry I misread your comment. I'm pretty convinced the minimal polynom must be of degree $n$ or at least $m$ where $n=mp^r$ with $r \geq  0$ and $ggT(m,n) = 1$ but at this point I don't have any idea how to prove this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for earlier confusions. Let $p$ be the characteristic of $K$ and let the minimal polynomial for $X$ in $K(X^n)[Z]$ be $f'$. Then $f'$ divides $Z^n-X^n$, but since $X$ is a transcendental element over $K$ it's clear that the degree of the extension is $n$, hence $f'=f$ by counting degrees. So $f$ is irreducible and is the minimal polynomial of $X$. The first bit of this is essentially a rephrasing of what you've already said.

Assume $p$ doesn't divide $n$ and that $K$ contains all roots of $X^n-1$. This polynomial is separable - $nX^{n-1}\neq0$, given $p$ doesn't divide $n$. Since $K$ contains all the roots, it is clear that all the roots must then be distinct (a repeated root would have to satisfy $a^{n-1}=0$, so $a=0$, but then $a^n-1=-1\neq0$). So we have $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\cdots,\zeta_n$, $n$ distinct roots of $X^n-1$ in $K$.

The polynomial $f:=Z^n-X^n$ is separable (since $p$ doesn't divide $n$) and it factors fully in $K(X)[Z]$ as $(Z-\zeta_1X)\cdots(Z-\zeta_nX)$. As $X$'s minimal polynomial in $K(X^n)[Z]$ is $f$, we then know the extension is normal and separable, hence Galois.

Now for the converse.

Assume the extension is Galois. The minimal polynomial $f$ must then be separable and split fully into linear factors in $K(X)[Z]$. $f$ is separable iff. the formal derivative $nZ^{n-1}$ is nonzero, and this is true iff. $p$ doesn't divide $n$. As $f$ splits fully into linear factors, write: $$Z^n-X^n=(Z-\alpha_1)\cdots(Z-\alpha_n)$$For distinct $\alpha_i\in K(X)$, $\alpha_1=X$. Define $\zeta_i:=\alpha_i\cdot X^{-1}$. Then $\zeta_i^n=1$ for every $i$. We know each $\zeta_i$ is distinct and is an element of $K(X)$, but we further want to know they are elements of $K$.

It is a general fact that any element of $K(X)$ algebraic over $K$ must be in $K$, however.

Let $\gamma\in K(X)$ satisfy $h(\gamma)=0$ where $h\in K[Z]$. Let $F$ be an algebraic closure of $K$. I know $h$ splits into linear factors in $F$ and all roots are elements $c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_k$ of $F$. Consider the roots of $h$ in $K(X)$: the embedding $K\hookrightarrow F$ ensures these are also all roots in $F(X)$. But we know all the roots of $h$ in $F$ are constant elements, so all the roots of $h$ in $F(X)$ are constant elements (no "$X$" terms). So it follows that the roots of $h$ in $K(X)$ were also all constant elements, in $K$, as desired. Hence $\gamma\in K$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I just posted a proof that I wrote in the update, it would be great if you can take a look and tell me if its correct or not :)

Comment: @hteica It looks broadly good to me but you need to justify $e_i\in K$.

Comment: $e_iX$ is in $K(X)$ and we can just divide $X$ and see that $e_i$ is thus in $K$, does this work?

Comment: @hteica No, in principle $e_i$ might be some element of $K(X)$ still. $K(X)/X\neq K$! (that formula doesn't make sense!)

Comment: $e_i$ by definition is the zeroes of $X^n-1 \in K[X]$, its an element of $K$ by definition. We have just shown that $e_iX \in K(X)$, so $e_i =e_iX /X \in K(X)$. Does it make sense to conclude that $e_i \in K$?

Comment: @hteica Nope. You *want* $e_i$ to be the zeroes of $X^n-1$, but all you know is that $e_i=a_i/X$ where $a_i^n=X^n$ and $a_i\in K(X)$. It's not guaranteed, without further work, that $a_i/X$ is an element of $K$.

Comment: $e_i$ is by definition the zeroes of $X^n-1$, we now know that $e_i \in K(X)$, does this not follow directly that $e_i \in K$? And to your comment: $a_i = e_iX$

Comment: @hteica Where do the $e_i$ come from? Normality of the Galois extension tells you there are $n$ distinct elements of $K(X)$, $a_i$, where $a_i^n=X^n$. It follows there are $n$ distinct elements $e_i:=a_i/X$ of $K(X)$ with $e_i^n=1$. Your set "$E$" doesn't need to exist in $K$? You keep saying, "by definition", but you don't get to make that definition! ""Which in this case can be written as $f=(Z-e_1X)\cdots(Z-e_nX)$"" there, the *only* thing you have knowledge of is that $(e_1X)^n=X^n$. Everything else must be deduced, not "defined"

Comment: $e_i$ is per definition elements of $E$, namely the zeroes of the polynom $X^n-1 \in K[X]$ ($p = char(K)$), see the first paragraph. Why don't we get to make the definition? the existence of $E$ follows immediately from the fact that $K$ is a field and $p = char(K)$

Comment: @hteica Yeah, but, when you're proving the converse implication, you don't yet know that $g$ even has any roots. The only thing you know is that $K(X)/K(X^n)$ is a Galois extension, and everything else needs to follow from there. In your forward direction proof you can use $E$ because you are given the assumption $E$ has $n$ elements in $K$. But in the backward implication, you don't know any of that. You need an extra step to go from $e_i\in K(X)$ to $e_i\in K$

Comment: $g$ has roots simply because $p$ doesn't divide $n$. Sorry maybe I could've worded it more clearly, the proof of (<-) is divided into 2 parts: 1. Show that $p$ divides $n$ leads to a contradiction. 2. Now that we know $p$ doesn't divide $n$, we show that $K$ contains all of $E$

Comment: @hteica $g$ has roots *in where*? !! You only know they are in $K(X)$, not in $K$. To show they are in $K$ needs more work. ""$e_i\in K(X)$ therefore $e_i\in K$"" is something needing proof

Comment: I think I understand your point now, thanks!

Comment: Also can you explain how $\sigma(\zeta_i) = 1$ follows from $\sigma(\alpha_i) = X$? In the beginning of the proof for the converse, how did you know that $f$ is the minimal polynom?

Comment: @hteica See the first paragraph for why $f$ is minimal. As for $\sigma(\zeta_i)=1$ I confess to making a small error but it's easy to fix. Will edit very soon

Comment: Thanks, it can be really easily fixed by $X^n = \sigma(\zeta_i^nX^n) = \sigma(\zeta_i^n)\sigma(X^n) = X^n \sigma(\zeta_i^n)$, thus $\sigma(\zeta_i^n) = 1$ and finally $\zeta_i^n=1$

Comment: @hteica Ah shame, that doesn't quite work either. Since $\zeta^n_i=1$ we already knew... but I have found an alternative solution!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't quite work? Our aim is to show $\zeta_i^n = 1$ and we have shown $\sigma(\zeta_i^n) = 1$, since $\sigma$ is an automorphism it fixes $1$ (the multiplicative identity) and therefore $\zeta_i^n = 1$

Comment: @hteica No, we already knew $\zeta^n_i=1$. We wanted $\zeta_i\in K$

Comment: Ah right, sorry my mind was messy. I'll take a look at your new proof

Comment: What if $a_k = b_k$? and you define $z = \frac{a_k}{b_k}$, let's say $z \neq 1$. We know then $z$ is a root of $g$ and it is in $K$, but that doesn't mean that every other roots are also in $K$, since there are only $\phi(n)$ many primitive roots. It would work if $z$ was a primitive root, but we don't know about this.

Comment: @hteica It seems I am not good at algebra today. In general it is however true that any element of $K(X)$ algebraic over $K$ must be in $K$. I'll add that in

Comment: I've just added some details to my proof, I think it shouldn't be hard to show $e_i \in K$ since we can just embed $K$ into $\overline{K}$ and $E \subset \overline{K}$ this doesn't have anything to do with $X$, and we know $e_i \in K(X)$, so $e_i \in \overline{K}$, do you think this works?

Comment: @hteica Yes, that's the idea. You don't seem to make a clear implication, though. What does $\overline{K}$ have to do with $K(X)$?

Comment: $\overline{K}$ doesn't have anything to do with $K(X)$ and that's the point, isn't it? Since $\overline{K}$ was defined independently of $X$ and we know $e_i \in K(X) \cap \overline{K}$ it must follow that $e_i \in K$

Comment: @hteica I'm not quite sure what the precise argument is there, see what I wrote for a hopefully clear version. But yes, that's essentially the point. As an aside, you're welcome for the solution and I will thank you back for posting the question and engaging with what I wrote. I do apologise for having made several mistakes writing this, I haven't "done algebra" in too long clearly.

Comment: Its ok, again, thanks for the solution, its been really helpful.